# AWS CDK Lambda Function Cannot Find Asset at Path

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, directory, path, aws-cdk

I'm trying to make a Lambda function using the AWS CDK They make it seem simple enough, but when I use cdk synth, it's giving me an error that the asset doesn't exist (even though it does exist). Here's my code:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
aws_lambda.Function(self, "lambda_function",
     runtime=aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
     handler="index.handler",
     code=aws_lambda.Code.from_asset(os.path.join(cwd, "lambda_functions/lambda"))
)
```

[image: CDK Directory]

The file exists, and the error message prints the directory I expect it to, so what's the issue here?

Comment: You didn't specific the .zip extension, so CDK is looking for a directory instead of your zip file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-lambda-readme.html#handler-code)
The `Code.from_asset(...)` requires you to **specify a directory or a .zip file**. From your code you're referencing a directory which is not true. Change the path to add .zip extension.

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
aws_lambda.Function(self, "lambda_function",
     runtime=aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
     handler="index.handler",
     code=aws_lambda.Code.from_asset(os.path.join(cwd, "lambda_functions/lambda.zip"))
)
```